# Bisection method in rectangles

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Suppose we start with a rectangle $R$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$. We divide $R$ into four congruent rectangles and with some rule (which I think doesn't have any connection with my question, so I won't mention it) we choose one of them, let's call it $R_1$. Then we do the same procedure for $R_1$ and continue in this way to obtain a sequence of rectangles $R\supset R_1 \supset R_2\supset  \dots \supset R_n \supset\dots$.

My question is whether this sequence has non-zero intersection and if this intersection is a single point.

My thoughts are the following: if it has non-zero intersection then it should indeed be just a point. To see that we suppose that it has two points and let $d$ be their distance. Since the diameter of our rectangles striclty decreases going to 0, for large $n$ we can find $R_n$ with diameter less than $d$. Then both these points should be in $R_n$ and have distance less than $d$, a contradiction. Is this true?

Now for the non-zero intersection I thought of Finite intersection property. Since $R$ is compact, our sequence constists of closed sets and every finite subcollection of these rectangles has obviously non-empty intersection, then it should be that the whole intersection is non-empty. Is this also true?

If both of the above are fine, is there a better way to see this result?

Thanks in advance

ps: I don't know which tags are appropriate for this post. Sorry.

Comment: Another way of looking at this would be take the co-ordinate of the left-hand side of each rectangle and show that this is non-decreasing and bounded above, hence tends to a limit. And this is the same limit as for the co-ordinate of the right-hand sides. Similarly with top and bottom. This uses properties of $\mathbb R$ directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb R^2$ is complete and the sequence of rectangles $R_n$ form a sequence of closed sets each being non-empty.

By Cantor's Intersection Property $\cap R_n\neq \emptyset $

Comment: you meant $\mathbb{R} ^{2}$ and not $\mathbb{R} $?